# Two processes created by child_process.exec

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm writing a pretty simple music server for my Raspberry Pi that will play MP#s on-demand. I can successfully launch an instance of `mpg123` using `child_process.exec()`, but the PID of this new process differs from the process actually decoding the music. This is important to me because I want to track the process in the event of a user wanting to stop the job (`child.kill()`). I'm executing as follows:

```
var child = child_process.exec('mpg123 "' + filename + '"');
console.log(JSON.stringify({pid: child.pid});
```

This outputs `{"pid":9444}`, and music starts playing. However, when I check `ps aux | grep mpg123`, I see two different processes:

```
pi        9444  0.0  0.1   1760   504 pts/1    S+   18:55   0:00 /bin/sh -c mpg123 "/home/pi/test.mp3"
pi        9445 11.0  0.6  14840  3112 pts/1    S+   18:55   0:00 mpg123 /home/pi/test.mp3
```

This latter process, 9445, is what's actually playing my mp3. If I hang onto `child` and `.kill()` upon request, the first job is killed but the second lingers, making the kill ineffective.

Is there a different way to create a process that avoids this, or some better way to kill it? I'd rather not have to track everything (eg, the command I used to create it) and try to track down the 'correct' one based on that (eg, `ps aux | grep <filename>`).

Comment: try `spawn`. `exec` runs shell as you can see

Comment: `child_process.spawn('mpg123', ['"' + filename + '"'])` gives me a PID, but it doesn't start music and a process isn't running when I grep for one in the console.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://gist.github.com/Sidnicious/1215700), `child_process.execFile(cmd, [args])` will spawn a new subshell, which is the pid of the `.exec`'d process. The subshell then created my instance of `mpg123`, which is the process I wanted to kill. Instead, I use:

```
var child = child_process.execFile('mpg123', [filename]); // note filename isn't enquoted
```

And when I want to kill it, I can simply:

```
child.kill(); // works
```